# How to make random frame animation in android?

Tags: android, animation, random, frame

I have a number of animated images(frames) like image_1,image_2 and image_3.I want to use this animated image in my application so I tried

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false" >

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/image_1"
        android:duration="2000"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/image_2"
        android:duration="50"/>
     <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/image_3"
        android:duration="50"/>

</animation-list>
```

And set this as background of my layout

```
 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if(hasFocus){

        final AnimationDrawable bgDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.animationLayout))
                .getBackground();
        ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.animationLayout))
                .post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        bgDrawable .start();
                    }
                });

        }
    }
}
```

But this shows the animation repeats every time in the same order. I want to make a `random frame animation` by using these images.How can i do this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5):

You can create a new `AnimationDrawable` and instead of binding the XML to it, just create frames manually and add them to `AnimationDrawable`.

```
AnimationDrawable animationDrawable = new AnimationDrawable();

animationDrawable.addFrame("You BitmapDrawable for first frame", 2000);
animationDrawable.addFrame("You BitmapDrawable for second frame", 50);
animationDrawable.addFrame("You BitmapDrawable for third frame", 50);
```

There are a good tutorials out there:

- [KeyFrame Animations](http://graphics-geek.blogspot.se/2013/02/devbytes-keyframe-animations.html)
- [Programmatic frame-by-frame animation example](http://androidforums.com/application-development/11620-programmatic-frame-frame-animation-examle-animationdrawable.html).

**Update:**

You can have a function to reset the `AnimationDrawable` and fill it up randomly at your specific time. This is just a pseudo code so adjust it for your need with correct syntax:

```
public AnimationDrawable shuffleFrame(AnimationDrawable ad) {

    ad = null;
    ad = new AnimationDrawable();

    // Create your Drawable frames here
    ...

    // For each Drawable, pick a random one here and add the frame
    ...
    ad.addFrame(Randomly picked frame, duration);


    return ad;
}
```

Call this function every time you want to shuffle the frames.

Comment: @DevuSoman, You gotta be kidding me. Just change the order of lines. `1. Second Frame`, `2. Third Frame`, `3. First Frame`

Comment: I am asking you that how to repeat the animation after a specific interval by changing order of frames

Comment: @DevuSoman, I have updated my answer as much as I understood your intention. Sorry if it's incorrect. I assume you are looking for a way to shuffle the frames.